# TypeError: initiate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I want to load data from csv to BigQuery by using this code.

```
df.to_gbq(table_for_uploading, upload_table, project_id=project_id, if_exists='replace', table_schema = [{'name':'execution_date','type': 'DATE'}])
```

I got this errors

```
TypeError: initiate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

Can anyone help why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect installing google-resumable-media==0.6 may solve your problem.

```
pip uninstall google-resumable-media
pip uninstall google-cloud-storage
pip install google-resumable-media==0.6.0
pip install google-cloud-storage==1.30.0
```

You can try it.